# React and Typescript: Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to add Typescript to my React project:

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove);
}

private handleMouseMove = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
  appStore.updateSideWidth(e.pageX);
}
```

But I got the following errors under `this.handleMouseMove`:

```
[ts]
Argument of type '(e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
Type '(e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 
'EventListenerObject'.
Property 'handleEvent' is missing in type '(e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) 
=> void'.
```

I tried:

1) @ts-ignore it works but I am reluctant to do that because that's why I am using Typescript
2) Use something like:

```
private handleMouseMove = (e: Event) => {
  appStore.updateSideWidth((e as React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>).pageX);
}
```

But got an error says cannot convert Event to MouseEvent type due to the lack of `altKey`.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

The event `e` will not be a `React` event as you are adding an event listener to the `document`. So the type of `e` will be just `MouseEvent`.

try:

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove);
}

private handleMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent) => {
  appStore.updateSideWidth(e.pageX);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried, but it generates a new error on the vdom: 
    Type '(e: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => void'.

Comment: You may want to try `(e: globalThis.MouseEvent)`